# Need Email Address from Google with Access Token that we receive from Alexa Skill?

Tags: php, google-oauth, alexa-skills-kit

I was able to Link Account using Google Auth v2 in Alexa Skill. And I am able to get Access Token. Now I want to get the Google Email address with which user has used to link account. So how can I get that Google Email Address?

Comment: I recomend going though the Google People api, try the person.get method it will return the full profile infomation.  The userinfo endpoint is not reliable and will only return a limited amount of information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Oauth2 Scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email".

Add the scope to your Google Client (Example with the Google Library for PHP):

```
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
// Your code here with Client ID, Secret, ...
$googleClient->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
```

That'll give you the E-Mail of the user.

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
// Your code here, the login code is in $_GET['code']

/**
* Get access token
*/
$token = $googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
$googleClient->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

// Create Google Auth Service with the Google Client
$google_auth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($googleClient);

// Get the userinfo 
$google_auth_info = $google_auth->userinfo->get();

// Get the E-Mail:
$email = $google_auth_info->email;

}
```

I think the part you're looking for is `authinfo->get()->email`, but i added a bit more context so you see how to use this.

Don't forget to enable this scope also in your Google Developers Console:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent -> Edit -> Step 2: Scopes

Comment: Note: the userinfo endpoint returns a limited amount of information and not always all of it.  A better option is to use the People api which you can use with the same email, profile scopes